# No puedo mostrar valor

Tags: java, android

**Buenas, tengo una duda. Estoy creando una variable globar con el tamaño de mi array. El problema con ello, es que a la hora de mostrar el valor siempre pone 0 (cero) incluso cuando eso en el debug se ve que el valor es otro. Les dejo capturas.

Variable global:

```
private int cont;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lugar donde le asigno el valor:

```
cont = data.size();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debugeando el valor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo seteo:

```
    String valor = String.valueOf(cont);
    tu.setText(""+valor);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso aquí la variable global contiene el valor correcto, pero como se ve en la captura el valor setea el 0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando lo hago así:

```
 tu.setText(""+cont);
```

El cont setea un 0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me explica el error? Gracias.

Código de donde saco el valor del tamaño de la lista:

```
private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ArrayList<TMODatosSeleccion>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TMODatosSeleccion> items) {
        super.onPostExecute(items);
        //Actualizar información
        adapter.updateData(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<TMODatosSeleccion> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");
        urlFinal = url;
        tmoDatosSeleccions.clear();
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Log.d("", "doInBackground: "+ doc);

            Elements data = doc.select("li.list-group-item.p-0.bg-light.upload-link");

            for (Element e1 : data) {
                String numeroCap = "";
                String urlMan = "";
                int contador = data.size();
                cont = contador;
                if(e1.select("div.col-10.text-truncate").size() > 0){
                    numeroCap = e1.select("a").get(0).text();
                    numeroCap = numeroCap.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "").trim();
                    if(e1.select("div.col-2.col-sm-1.text-right").size() > 0 ){
                        urlMan = e1.select("a.btn.btn-default.btn-sm").get(0).attr("href");
                        if(urlMan.contains("/paginated")){
                            urlMan.replace("/paginated", "/cascade");
                            tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlMan));
                        }else{
                            tmoDatosSeleccions.add(new TMODatosSeleccion(numeroCap, urlMan));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tmoDatosSeleccions;
    }
}
```

Método onCreate donde lo ejecuto:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tmonline_capitulos_seleccion);
    
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearColores);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvCapitulosSeleccion);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new TMODatoSeleccionAdapter(tmoDatosSeleccions, TMOnlineCapitulosSeleccion.this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Content content = new Content();
    content.execute();

    titulo();
}
```

Método donde quiero mostrarlo:

```
private void titulo(){
    tu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTuSeleccionManga);
    manga = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMangaSeleccionManga);
    online = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvOnlineSeleccionManga);

    tu.setText(""+cont);
    manga.setText("MANGA");
    online.setText("ONLINE");

    tu.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(TMOnlineCapitulosSeleccion.this, R.color.tmoTitulo));
    manga.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(TMOnlineCapitulosSeleccion.this, R.color.tmoTitulo));
    online.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(TMOnlineCapitulosSeleccion.this, R.color.tmoTitulo));
}
```

Comment: El codigo real debe ir como texto.. si queres mostrar capturas del debug, por favor recortalas para que se vea solamente eso y no haya que abrir mil imagenes para entenderlo...

Comment: Si no pones el codigo es muy dificil ayudarte

Comment: He añadido el código @unknow

Comment: Vale, cortaré las imágenes @gbianchi

Comment: Al ser una tarea asincrona donde seteas el valor, nunca vas a saber cuando ha terminado la ejecución y lo ha seteado. Si justo a continuación de lanzar la tarea asíncrona, vas a comprobarlo, pues muy posiblemente no tenga valor. Y si lo haces depurando paso a paso, ya no se parecerá jamás a la realidad, en la que las cosas se ejecutan sin parar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución, cree la variable global como ya he mostrado:

```
private int cont;
```

Luego, en el `onPostExecute()` le asigné el valor del `array` a la variable:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TMODatosSeleccion> items) {
    super.onPostExecute(items);
    //Actualizar información
    adapter.updateData(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cont = items.size();//esta es la línea que agregué
}
```